# how can i include base_url inside background url in css Codeigniter

Tags: php, html, css, codeigniter

Hello guys i need help i am trying to include base_url inside background url in a css file but it is not working please i need help in this.

```
  background: url('<?php echo base_url();?>assets/images/re_1.png') repeat;
color: #413c35;
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
overflow-x: hidden;
```

Comment: you can not run php code in css,don't try this

Comment: so what can i do instead?

Comment: you can use javascript + php,using javascript you can apply a style and using php you can pass base_url() to java script

Comment: or you can provide relative path define by @Sumanta736  http://www.coffeecup.com/help/articles/absolute-vs-relative-pathslinks/

Comment: Where is css file placed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
body {
 background:#356aa0 url(../img/background.png) repeat-x;
 color:#fff;
}
```

And now call it:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?=base_url()?>css/style.css"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

css

```
background:url('assets/images/re_1.png');
color: #413c35;
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
overflow-x: hidden;
```

html

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url('example.css');?>">
```

example.css change to your css file path

Answer (score 0):

write css at your view

```
<style>
.blah{ 
   background: url('<?php echo base_url();?>assets/images/re_1.png') repeat;
  color: #413c35;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  }
</style>
```